# Collections.frequency returning 0 when checking -1 values in ArrayList

Tags: java, collections

```
List line = [0, -1, 28, 0, 50, 0, -1, 75, 0] // pseudocode
System.out.println(Collections.frequency(line, -1));
```

Why does `Collections.frequency` return `0` when I check the `-1` value?

Comment: What is `line`? Does it contain -1?  We need more information.

Comment: i think that is the name of the collection he want to check.

Comment: I'm interested in its type

Comment: updated question, the type is List, the value is an ArrayList in fact, there are -1 values, but the frequency returns 0 somehow

Comment: of what type is the list?

Comment: What type are the *entries* of the list?  Integers?  Strings?  Longs? BigIntegers?  Something else?

Comment: myNumbers.add(key, -1); - this is how add them, looks like an int type

Comment: Are you sure line is of type List and not of type Map?

Comment: need more code to help.

Comment: is your `ArrayList` `myNumbers` or `line` ?

Comment: Ohh it was a String type -1, sorry guys :D, there was a line somewhere in my code .toString() that was the joke

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is how , collections.frequency works:**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class stackexample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> values = Arrays.asList( 5, 0, 0, 2 );
        int occurrences = Collections.frequency(values, 0);
        System.out.println("occurrences of zero is " + occurrences); //shows 0 but answer should be 2
    }
}
```

**In your case, it is returning zero beacuse, -1 is not available in your collection**

Answer (score 1):

You have no items in `line` that have the value -1.

Answer (score 0):

According to java docs

```
Returns the number of elements in the specified collection equal to the specified object.     
More formally, returns the number of elements e in the collection such that (o == null ? e
== null : o.equals(e)).
```

So there is no match so returning 0 see below

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#frequency(java.util.Collection, java.lang.Object)